# Wishlist All Product Addtocart In Magento

Tags: php, magento

How to solve more then one items addtocart from wishlist to cart, using API OR programmatically in magento.

**Below Is my API code** and it work for single item but not more then one.

```
$customer_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customerId');
$itemCollection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
    ->addCustomerIdFilter($customer_id);
//echo "<pre>";print_r($itemCollection->getData());die();
$cartData = array();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer);
if($itemCollection) {
    foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
        if($product_id != 0) {
            if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $product_id) {
                $qty = $item->getQty();
                // Get customer session
                $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
                $type = $product->getTypeId();
                if($type == 'simple') {
                    try {
                        $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
                        $quote->collectTotals()->save();

                        $success = 1;
                        $cartData['response'] = "Product Added To Cart Successfully!";
                        $item->delete(); break;
                    }
                    catch(Exception $ex) {
                        $success = 0;
                        $cartData['error'] = $ex->getMessage();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $success = 0;
                    $cartData['error'] = "Sorry product not available....!!!"; 
                }
            }
            else {
                $success = 0; 
                $cartData['error'] = "Sorry product not available....!!!"; 
            }
        }
        else {
            //echo $item->getProduct()->getId();
            //$qty = $item->getQty();
            $successmsg = ''; $commma = ''; $errormsg = '';
            // Get customer session
            //$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($product->getData());
            $type = $product->getTypeId();
            if($type == 'simple') {
                try {
                    $quote->addProduct($product,$item->getQty());
                    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
                    $success = 1;
                    $successPro[] = 1;
                    $item->delete();
                }
                catch(Exception $ex) {
                    $success = 0;
                    $errorPro[] = $ex->getMessage();
                }
            }
            if(count($successPro) > 0) {
                $successmsg = count($successPro)." Products Added into cart Successfully";
            }
            if(count($errorPro) > 0 && count($successPro) > 0) {
                $commma = ' , ';
            }
            if(count($errorPro) > 0) {
                $errormsg = count($errorPro)." Products not Added into cart.";
            }
            $cartData['response'] = $successmsg.$commma.$errormsg; 
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me how to solve this issue.